# Blazor server app HttpClient call to http time out

Tags: blazor, httpclient, mixed-content

Request to http: server from my Blazor server Azure-hosted app results in a timeout.

Request to https: server works.

Requests from browser work if sent to the http resource, and fail (blocked) if sent from https.

How I understood there is a same mixed content issue in my app.
How do I bypass this? Is it possible?

API server I need to send requests does not accept https.

Many thanks!

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVersion()
{
    var client = new HttpClient 
                     {
                         BaseAddress = new Uri("http://webservice....")
                     };

    var getVersion = new Version();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", getVersion);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return response;
}
```

Searching on the internet gives some perception that this is not going to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was not the mixed content issues.
Strangely sorted it by using PostAsync method instead os PostAsJsonAsync.
Following works without any issues.

```
using System.Text;
public static async Task<string> GetVersion()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var getVersion = new Version();
        string json = "{\""+"getVersion"+"\": {}}";
        var requestData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(
            "http://webservice....", requestData);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Solves my problem! Just a note: I was trying to access an API endpoint hosted in Azure App Service. PostAsJsonAsync and PutAsJsonAsync don't work. GetFromJsonAsync works fine. To be safe, use PostAsync and PutAsync. But all of this is not an issue with localhost API.